# Set pen/color for Polyline()?

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

I use different WinGDI-functions to send data to the printer, here vector data are sent using function Polyline(). Now I want to set a color for this polyline, so I tried calling functions SetDCPenColor() and SetDCBrushColor() prior to the Polyline()-call.

Unfortunately none of them had any influence, the resulting lines are still black. So...what could be wrong here? Which is the correct function to change the colour of such a polyline?

Thanks!

Edit: the code which does not work

```
SetDCPenColor(*pdc,RGB(rval,gval,bval));
Polyline(*pdc,points,n);
```

Comment: Are you selecting the pen you have created into the device context w/ SelectObject ?  If you are please add the failing code.

Comment: Alex K. see code above, I just set the colour prior to drawing...

Comment: You need to create a pen then select it as in [Setting the Pen or Brush Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145096(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @AlexK. got it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the DC pen and brush colors doesn't have any effect unless you have the DC pen and/or brush selected into the DC.  They are not selected into the DC by default.

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
::BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
::SetDCPenColor(ps.hdc, RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));  // has no effect
::MoveToEx(ps.hdc, x0, y0, nullptr);
::LineTo(ps.hdc, x1, y1);
::EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

To use the DC pen or brush, you need to first select the DC object into the DC.

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
::BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
auto oldPen = ::SelectObject(ps.hdc, ::GetStockObject(DC_PEN));  // <<<<
::SetDCPenColor(ps.hdc, RGB(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));  // now this works
::MoveToEx(ps.hdc, x0, y0, nullptr);
::LineTo(ps.hdc, x1, y1);
::SelectObject(ps.hdc, oldPen);  // remember to select it back out
::EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```